# "Unknown error" in sweetjs file using Visual Studio Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, sweet.js

I'm *just* starting to learn about [Sweet.JS](http://sweetjs.org/), and was excited to realize it's already built into Visual Studio 2013 Web Essentials.

I decided to first make a macro to shorten anonymous `function`s to `fn`.

```
macro fn {
    rule {
        $params $body
    } => {
        function $params $body
    }
}
```

Entering this in the online sweet.js editor gives me:

[image: sweet.js editor output]

Visual Studio, however, is giving me the a helpful error message of "Unknown error":

[image: Helpful error message: "Unknown error"]

I get the same error with any input I've tried, including an empty file, which is bizarre to me.  I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting this issue.

At the moment, I don't know what information is relevant, but I'll be happy to edit this question to supply any information you guys need to help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what version of sweet.js VS is using? (I had no idea VS had integrated sweet.js!)

Comment: It's not automatically integrated.  There's a very helpful plugin called VS Web Essentials that (supposedly) supports it.  And no, I can't seem to find the sweet.js version.  The only hint that WebEssentials even supports it seems to be on http://vswebessentials.com/features/general.

Comment: Looks like web essentials is on github so maybe that can help track down the problem: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013